# How to find and replace the pattern ");" in a text file?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a text file which contains special characters. I want to replace `");"` with `"firstdata);seconddata"`.
The catch is that both `")"` and `";"` should be together and then replaced with `"firstdata);seconddata"`.

I have the following code.

```
import re
string = open('trial.txt').read()
new_str = re.sub('[);]', 'firstdata);seconddata', string)
open('b.txt', 'w').write(new_str)
```

Please, suggest me how to change my code to get the right output.

Comment: `[);]` is confusing... it is a set of chars containing 2 things that I would always escape and no match length... you dont need a regexp to match strings, as @ryanmarvin points out... this regex would be valid though `"\)\;"`

Comment: also this must be a duplicate

Comment: `[teach-me]`   `[);]` means "one character that can be either `)` or `;`". Please read up on regular expression syntax. If you're having problems with escaping `)` (it is indeed a special character in python REs), please read up on the escaping. Possible solution that avoids escaping problems: `[)];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
import re

with open("file.txt", "r") as rfile:
    s = rfile.read()
    rplce = re.sub('\);', "REPLACED", s)
with open("file.txt", "w") as wfile:
    wfile.write(rplce)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in str.replace() method in Python

```
string = "foobar);"
string.replace(");", 'firstdata);seconddata')  # -> 'foobarfirstdata);seconddata'
```

Here are the docs for common string operations like this in Python
https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use more simple way.

```
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as input_file:
   with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
       for line in input_file:
           x = line.replace('findtext','replacetext')
           output_file.write(x)
```